# Why is my background color not changing when I change the theme on Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, colors, themes, eclipse-rcp

I have been trying lately to change the theme of my eclipse workspace to something easier on my eyes. After doing some digging, it seems like it should be pretty simple to change the theme on Eclipse, I went to  Window -> Preferences -> Appearance -> Color Theme and chose a darker theme. [The theme I chose and what it should look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s7f7j.png)

However, after applying and closing, only the code editor has been switched, not the other elements of eclipse 
[What it looks like after I apply and close](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LejGD.png)
Does anyone know how to fix this so that the theme affects the entire application and not just the editor?

Answer (score 1):

That's not the built-in theming support, which is configured from the main **Appearance** preference page, so ymmv. See if there's an option there that you find acceptable.